# Does UIWebView support javascript-based double-click events?

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, double-click

As usual, I'm trying to do something the easiest way possible, in this case 
implement a double-tap handler on a UIWebView like so:

`<div id="foo" ondblclick="clickHandler(this);" ... >`

It works fine in Safari and Firefox, and I know the code containing
clickHandler is loading on the iPhone thanks to a now-annoying
alert stmt at the end of loading.

If I change `ondblclick` to `onclick` it works on both the device and
the simulator.

From reading similar queries it would seem that I need to intercept
the taps in ... and then run my JavaScript code with the
`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method, but then how do I
know the JS id of the target?  I no like that, would rather 
write a pure HTML/DOM/JS solution.  Or since my app is about
80% web content, should I be using phonegap instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MobileSafari doesn't support the double click event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html#t06). Besides, double tapping on MobileSafari already has a well-defined operation — zooming.

You can install an `onClick` handler, and detect the time intervals between 2 clicks to determine whether it's a double click or not.